# Overloading function for specific template parameters (C++ partial template specialization in rust)

Tags: templates, rust

I'm trying to make a function that can take a lambda that takes a reference and a lambda that takes a value.

An example will probably help since its difficult to describe.

```
fn derivative<F, R>(f: &F, x: f64) -> R
where F: Fn(f64) -> R,
      R: Div<f64, Output=R> + Sub<Output=R>

{
    let epsilon = 1e-7;
    (f(x + epsilon / 2.0) - f(x - epsilon / 2.0)) / epsilon
}

fn derivative<F, R>(f: &F, x: f64) -> R
    where F: Fn(&f64) -> R,
          R: Div<f64, Output=R> + Sub<Output=R>
{
    let epsilon: f64 = 1e-7;
    (f(&(x + epsilon / 2.0)) - f(&(x - epsilon / 2.0))) / epsilon
}
```

This function approximates the derivative of `f` and I'd like to support both `Fn<f64>` and `Fn<&f64>`. In C++ I would do partial template specialization (just a fancy term for pattern matching template arguments) is there some thing similar to this in rust?

I thought that the syntax would look like the example code, but apparently the compiler tells me that `derivative` has been redefined [E4028].

Or is there an even easier way to implement this behavior?

Comment: Doing this with traits is possible, but complex. The simplest approach in my opinion is to omit the second declaration altogether and require the closure to take `f64`. There's very little benefit to being able to accept both.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure you can do this without lifetime GATs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recently, where I wanted to specialize a method based on type parameters. Here is a standalone example that seems to work:

```
// trait is specialized for each specialization
pub trait SomeTraitSpecification<T> {
    fn someFunctionImpl(&self, value: T);
}

// base trait

struct SomeStructure;
impl SomeStructure {
    // function entry
    // where clause restricts function options down to specific specialization function
    pub fn someFunction<T>(&self, value: T) where Self: SomeTraitSpecification<T> {
        // does nothing but call the specialized function
        self.someFunctionImpl(value);
    }
}

// implement SomeTraitSpecification for each type you want to call SomeStructure on
// declared in different impl blocks to avoid redefinitions

// f32 specialization
impl SomeTraitSpecification<f32> for SomeStructure {
    fn someFunctionImpl(&self, value: f32) {
        println!("float!");
    }
}

// i32 specialization
impl SomeTraitSpecification<i32> for SomeStructure {
    fn someFunctionImpl(&self, value: i32) {
        println!("integer!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let structure = SomeStructure {};
    structure.someFunction(4); // calls i32 specialization
    structure.someFunction(5.0); // calls f32 specialization
}
```

It's a little verbose, but it does work. The `SomeTraitSpecialization` trait is used to provide specializations. The "where" clause on the `someFunction<T>` is where the magic happens -- I've provided some comments that add some clarification.
Hopefully you can modify this to be useful.